# how to expand text mouse hover - css3, jQuery, JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to recreate the [hover over slide effect found here](http://madebydb.com/), whereby when you hover over the d/B it expands to d/Binaural, except that I am trying to do it for 'dsr' expanding to 'deep seeded records'.

My question is can I do it with CSS3 and HTML5 alone or do I have to do it with jQuery?
I am trying to use it for a squarespace site I am building if that makes any difference, I don't think it will re; the requisite code.

If anyone could help out with the code required that would be really great, I am very much a beginner.

Comment: *"or do I have to do it with jQuery?"* - One never *has to* do anything with jQuery, given that jQuery is "just" a collection of JS functions that can't do anything one couldn't code for oneself in plain JS. (This is not a criticism of jQuery. I like jQuery.)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using CSS transitions:

CSS

```
    <style>
       .b:hover .revelator{
        width:100px;
    }

    .revelator{
        display:inline-block;
        transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955); 
        width:0;
        overflow:hidden;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    </style>
```

HTML

```
<span class="b">/B<span class="revelator">inaural</span></span>
```

The code doing all the magic is the **transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.455,0.0,0.515,0.955)**

Of course this code does not have any styling other than the hover effect.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!